# untrack ignored files on production server with git

Tags: git

For some reason I have several files on my production server which show up as `Changes not staged for commit`

```
modified:   node/peerflix/README.md
modified:   node/peerflix/app.js
deleted:    node/peerflix/app.js.bak
modified:   node/peerflix/index.js
modified:   node/peerflix/package.json
```

I have a `.gitignore` file in the `node` directory which just contains a simple `*` to ignore everything in that folder.

I have no idea how this happened on the production server. But is there a way to get rid of those tracked but ignored files without commiting on my production server?

EDIT:
In case people missed it: It's on a production server. I don't want to commit unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/3691891

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Before you guys mark this as a duplicate READ the question. WITHOUT committing